# Utilização do Ciclo For e Arrays

Tags: javascript, array, funções, for

Existem dois exercícios que eu preciso resolver utilizando um ciclo (ou laço) FOR... Em um deles, eu preciso pegar um `array` x como parâmetro em uma função, e multiplicar todos os seus elementos entre si e me retornar o resultado. o outro exercício é escrever uma função no qual um numero x, como parâmetro, seja calculado seu fatorial (ou seja, a multiplicação dele mesmo por números inteiros anteriores ao mesmo)... 
o código que escrevi para o exercicio do array:

```
function produto (pr) {
  var total = 1;
    for (var i = 0; i < pr.lenght; i++) {
   total = total * pr[i];
}
  return total
}
```

o da fatoração:

```
function fatorial (x) {
  var fat = 1
for (var i = 0; i <= x; i++){
        fat = fat * x * i;
 }
  return fat;
}
```

nenhum dos dois funcionam. Como eu posso resolve-los ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O primeiro é apenas um erro de sintaxe:
ao invés de `pr.lenght` o certo seria `pr.length`

No meu exemplo apliquei alguns padrões de tipagem de variável. Ao invés de `var`, use `let` para escopos dentro de função.

```js
function produto (pr) {
  let total = 1;
  for (let i = 0; i < pr.length; i++) {
   if(pr[i] === 0)
    continue;
   
   total = total * pr[i];
  }
  return total;
}

console.log(produto([1,2,3,4]))
```

Já o segundo, ele está bem errado a questão da lógica, eu criei um exemplo para que você possa ver:

```js
function fatorial (x) {
  let fatorial = 1;
    for (let i = x; i > 0; i--){    
      fatorial = fatorial * i;   
    }
  return fatorial;
}

console.log(fatorial(5))
```

acredito que a chave da solução está na criação do for:

```
for (let i = x; i > 0; i--){
```

minha variável i ao invés de zero, ela começa valendo o valor de x, e continuo o laço até que ela seja 1.